# Numerous android spinners

Tags: android, spinner

I am designing a "score-entry" app that basically takes all the games for a given day (this can range from a few to a few hundred on any given day) and lists them for score entry. Each game obviously has 2 scores (1 for each team). I am doing score selection of course with android spinners populated with 0-30 for each individual team score. Each game listed has a unique id (which was obtained from a MySQL DB) and that is what I am using as the id for each spinner.

The issue I am having: I create all the spinners (we'll call them spinner1 [for 1st team] and spinner2 [for 2nd team]) for each game. They are  all listed within the app at the same time (which needs to happen due to the varying times that games will end etc). When I test to see which spinner Id has had a selection made it always returns the same Id which means when I send the spinner data back to php for decoding and updating of the database - it will update the same game id, which does me no good.

What I really wanted to do was create each spinner with the name: "spinner1" + gameid but from what I am reading that is not possible. I need that right game ID sent back when a score is put in and I am guessing my issue is there is not a unique identifier for spinner1 & spinner2 each time through the loop that creates the spinners. They have to be created dynamically due to the varying number of games that can happen in a given day.

Any suggestions:

Comment: You could probably use tags something along the lines of `myspinner.setTag(thisgame)` (when creating the spinner). Then with something along the lines of  `thisgame = (vartype) myspinner.getTag();` (when sending/posting the data).

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] of the problem?

Comment: MikeT - i never thought about the tags - that might work - thank you.

Comment: cricket_007 - I am going to try MikeT's suggestion -  if I still can't get where I need to be doing that I'll let you know

Comment: MikeT - same type of issue -  whether I tag it or ID it - only thing listener is detecting is the "last" game id. Ideally what I really need is the equivalent of: Spinner spinner1[] = new Spinner; where I can use spinner1 & spinner2 repeatedly as the spinner names just adding a new "array" spinner through each looped game. Have to stop for awhile on it now anyway - lots of rainouts happening today - ugh

Comment: Here is what basically the screen look like (these are actual games for today) - there is only a few on the screen shot as that is setup in scrollview - I believe the game list is 56 games for today: [IMG]http://i66.tinypic.com/2a9zdpj.png[/IMG]

Answer (score 0):

What about starting with the app by

1) having the app request a up-to-date list of "games still needing scores".

2) Then you select which game you want to set the score for, which sends you to a new activity (a template that is the same for all games... containing two spinners, if you wish... no need for spinner ids... although you would have to figure out a way to differentiate between the two teams... maybe always do alphabetical).

Just send the game id as an intent extra to the new activity, and post the score from that activity to something like:

http://yourwebsite.com/uploadscore.php?game=438765387262435&team1score=20&team2score=21

I also think setting a maximum selectable score is a bad idea... you never know whats going to happen.

Comment: the "games-still-needing-scores" suggestion won't work - need access to all the games for the day due to occasionally the folks who phone the scores in report them wrong and they need to be changed. As far as the maximum selectable score - there is a reason it is at 30 - business has been around 10 years and we've never gone over that - if/when that happens - I'll raise the limit

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your responses and I have answered my own question. It was pretty much a DUH moment when I finally figured it out. The reason I kept getting the same game ID returned was I kept "asking" for the id by the id of the spinner name (i.e. spinner1 for the first team on a given game). Of course after it loops through creating all the spinners I need for a given day, the only one that spinner1's id would have on a listener is the last one (I was using spinner1.getId() to get the id of the utilized spinner on a score change). I changed the listener to get the parent spinner instead of spinner1 (i.e. the clicked on spinner would be the parent) and utilized: parent.getId(); to make sure it was returning the right game id. It was. Problem solved.